# Change . visible property in array by filtering based on array of indexes

Tags: javascript, arrays

Need to create a new array3 from array1 by making visible false for indexes not present in array2.

Here in the following example I have indexes 0,2. So The outcome array must have visible as false for 1,3

```
var array1 = [{
    "visible": "true",
    "id": 0
}, {
    "visible": "true",
    "id": 1
}, {
    "visible": "true",
    "id": 2
}, {
    "visible": "true",
    "id": 3
}];

var array2 = [0,2]
```

Expected outcome:

```
array3 = [{
    "visible": "true",
    "id": 0
}, {
    "visible": "false",
    "id": 1
}, {
    "visible": "true",
    "id": 2
}, {
    "visible": "false",
    "id": 3
}];
```

Answer (score 4):

One option could be to use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on array1 and use [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) on array2. Inside map, create a copy of the original object so that the original objects in array1 will not be mutated.

```js
var array1 = [{
  "visible": "true",
  "id": 0
}, {
  "visible": "true",
  "id": 1
}, {
  "visible": "true",
  "id": 2
}, {
  "visible": "true",
  "id": 3
}];

var array2 = [0, 2];

var array3 = array1.map(i => {
  var dc = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(i));
  dc.visible = array2.includes(i.id).toString();
  return dc;
});


console.log(array3);
console.log(array1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could turn `array2` into a Set for a constant lookup-time:

```js
function hide(array1, array2) {
    const indexes = new Set(array2);
    return array1.map(o => !indexes.has(o.id) ? ({...o, visible: "false" }) : o);
}

var array1 = [{
  "visible": "true",
  "id": 0
}, {
  "visible": "true",
  "id": 1
}, {
  "visible": "true",
  "id": 2
}, {
  "visible": "true",
  "id": 3
}];

console.log(hide(array1, [0, 2]));
```

This will only do what is asked: turn `visible` to `"false"` where the `id` is not listed. It will not do the opposite, i.e. it will not turn `visible` to `"true"` when the `id` *is* listed: it will just copy the original setting.

If also the opposite should happen, then the original value of `visible` no longer plays a role:

```js
function hide(array1, array2) {
    const indexes = new Set(array2);
    return array1.map(o => ({...o, visible: indexes.has(o.id)+"" }));
}

var array1 = [{
  "visible": "true",
  "id": 0
}, {
  "visible": "true",
  "id": 1
}, {
  "visible": "true",
  "id": 2
}, {
  "visible": "true",
  "id": 3
}];

console.log(hide(array1, [0, 2]));
```

Note that it would make more sense if `visible` were a boolean instead of a string (`false` and `true` instead of `"false"` and `"true"`).